# BD Campos primarios en varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día tengo una duda, estoy trabjando con 2 bases de datos al mismo tiempo, para hacer un tabla, funciona bien hice algunos joins y me trae los datos, pero, hay un dato que no me lo trae, y estuve verificando y lo unico diferente que encontre es:

Que en mi tabla **A** el dato tiene ´`varchar(4)`´ y en mi tabla **C** tiene `varchar(6)` las llaves llevan el mismo nombre `a.id_org = c.id_org`

¿Es necesario que sean identicas en el valor, para que me traiga el dato?

Comment: si, las llaves primarias y las llaves foráneas utilzadas durante un `JOIN` necesitan ser del mismo **tipo y longitud**

Comment: De acuerdo muchas gracias, ingresa tu comentario como respuesta para elegirte como mejor resp

Comment: Acabo de verificar y el tipo y longitud de los campos no afecta, lo que si puede afectar es que lo que este guardado en una columna y otra columna no se correspondan, ejemplo: `0001` y `000001` [Prueba](https://rextester.com/RXM41869)

Comment: precisamente @VictorPerdomo tu lo estas mostrando, el tipo de dato en tu ejemplo es distinto por lo tanto si importa y lo necesario en estos casos es que sean mismo tipo y longitud por que son llave primaria y foránea

Comment: ¿Podría ponerse un enlace a alguna fuente (preferiblemente oficial) que indique que deben ser (o no) del mismo tipo y longitud?

Comment: saludos @AlvaroMontoro la  única referencia que tengo a la mano es esta https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj13590.html, en el apartado de `PK` y `FK` indica que el valor de la columna se debe corresponder

Comment: No sé, amigo aun no lo veo algo debo estar haciendo mal https://rextester.com/HXRM41265 según veo hablas del valor es como te indico los valores de las dos columnas si debe ser igual, pero en la definición de las columnas en sí no necesariamente tiene que ser de la misma longitud y tipo, claro esto no quiere decir que sea una buena práctica esta mal hacerlo pero sí se puede incluso lo probé en `SQL Server` y no da errores. Puedes hacer esto por ejemplo `PK DECIMAL` y `FK INT`

Comment: yo probé poniendo la PK como varchar(30) y la fk como int(30) en sql server 2014 y me da este error `Column, parameter, or variable #2: Cannot specify a column width on data type int.`

Comment: ademas si aun poniendo ambas como varchar pero una de 20 de longitud y otra de 30 de longitud @VictorPerdomo me marcar este error `Column 'uno.id' is not the same length or scale as referencing column 'dos.uno_id' in foreign key 'fk_dos_uno'. Columns participating in a foreign key relationship must be defined with the same length and scale.
Msg 1750 Level 16 State 0 Line 1
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
`

Comment: Si me da ese error en el `FK` cuando hago directamente el `CREATE` de la tabla pero si agregas la `FK` con el `ALTER` de la tabla no da ese error. Técnicamente si es posible hacerlo.

Comment: cierto es, pero bueno a modo comentario no lo considero válido desde un `ALTER` por que al menos para mi debería ser válido tanto con el `alter ` como con el `create`

Comment: @shadow según entendí la pregunta, no dice nada de llaves foráneas, por lo que para hacer el join no es necesario que sea el mismo tipo de datos

Comment: @Lamak igual me confundí pero me atreví a responder de este modo por su título que dice **campos primarios**

Comment: @shadow mi Tabla A tiene el campo en primario y mi tabla C tiene el campo indexado como foraneo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al momento de relacionar 2 tablas por medio de `PRIMARY KEY` y de una `FOREIGN KEY` debes tener en cuenta que:

1. ambas deben ser del mismo tipo: (`VARCHAR, DECIMAL o INT, etc`)
2. ambas deben ser de la misma longitud, es decir `INT(10) o VARCHAR(15)`

**EJEMPLO 1**

Tabla principal

```
CREATE TABLE tablaUno(
  id VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(10)
);
```

Tabla dependiente

```
CREATE TABLE tablaDos(
  id VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  tablaUno_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_tablaDos_tablaUno FOREIGN KEY(tablaUno_id) REFERENCES tablaUno(id)
);
```

La creación de las tablas se hace de manera exitosa, puesto que tanto `id` de la `tablaUno` como `tablaUno_id` de la tabla `tablaDos` son del mismo tipo: `VARCHAR` y la misma longitud `10`

**EJEMPLO 2**

Voy a tratar de repetir la creación de las tablas anteriores, pero esta vez mira la longitud de `tablaUno_id` como aunque es de tipo `VARCHAR` esta vez tiene una longitud de `120`

Tabla princial

```
CREATE TABLE tablaUno(
  id VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(10)
);
```

Tabla dependiente

```
CREATE TABLE tablaDos(
  id VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  tablaUno_id VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_tablaDos_tablaUno FOREIGN KEY(tablaUno_id) REFERENCES tablaUno(id)
);
```

**ME DARÁ EL SIGUIENTE ERROR**

> Msg 1753 Level 16 State 0 Line 1 Column 'tablaUno.id' is not the same
>   length or scale as referencing column 'tablaDos.tablaUno_id' in
>   foreign key 'fk_tablaDos_tablaUno'. Columns participating in a foreign
>   key relationship must be defined with the same length and scale. Msg
>   1750 Level 16 State 0 Line 1 Could not create constraint or index. See
>   previous errors.

Que es muy descriptivo al indicarte la longitud entre la llave primaria y la llave foránea no es la misma

**EJEMPLO 3**

Si ahora trato de crear una tabla con una llave primaria de tipo `VARCHAR(10)` de este modo

```
CREATE TABLE tablaUno(
  id VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(10)
);
```

Pero la trato de vincular a una llave foránea de tipo `INT(10)`

```
CREATE TABLE tablaDos(
  id VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  tablaUno_id INT(10) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_tablaDos_tablaUno FOREIGN KEY(tablaUno_id) REFERENCES tablaUno(id)
);
```

Aún cuando ambas tienen la misma longitud, el tipo es distinto

**ME DARÁ EL SIGUIENTE ERROR**

> Msg 2716 Level 16 State 1 Line 1 Column, parameter, or variable #2:
>   Cannot specify a column width on data type int.

Comment: Es verdad, por lo regular suelo trabajar con INT para el manejo de llaves primarias y foraneas,siempre utilizo la longitud default de 11 y me funciona, pero en este caso la BD en la que estoy trabjando utiliza Varchar como llaves primarias y foraneas, en verdad muchas gracias !!